# Eclipse C++ debugger not displaying variable values

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have used Eclipse for Java coding without any problem. With C++ Eclipse (Indigo), my problem is that, I am **not able to see the values of the variables** when I put the mouse over them ! It just shows the definition of the variable.

In Java if we right click on a variable then we get an option like `"Inspect value"`. That option is also not visible in C++ eclipse.
How to solve this issue ? Is there any plugin or configuration am I missing ?

Have freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 in Virtual Box (Windows XP Host). Then installed g++ 4.6, Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse CDT. In `"Debug Configurations"`, it shows:

```
Debugger: gdb/mi
Advanced: Automatically track values of "Variables" and "Registers"
GDB Debugger: gdb
GDB command file: .gdbinit
GDB Command set: Standard(Linux)
Protocol: mi
(unchecked) Verbose console mode
(unchecked) Use full file path to set breakpoints
```

I am able to put break points and stop the execution there, the only problem is seeing values.

Comment: Did you compile with debug enabled ? (gcc option -g)

Comment: @Offirmo, I haven't checked that. But shouldn't eclipse do it automatically ? If not then where to set this option ?

Comment: I just tried a default "hello world" project in eclipse, and indeed debug options are activated by default. Check for you by opening the console window, doing "build > clean" then "build project" and check for a -g option (or -g3). This way we'll be sure.

Comment: The setting is in "Project -> build configuration -> set active -> debug"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, due to optimizations those values don't exist at that point. For example, consider:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int i=SomeFunctions();
    if(i>3) Foo();
    else
    {
       Bar();
       Baz();
    }
    // breakpoint here
    return 8;
}
```

The compiler is free to keep `i` entirely in a register. By the time you hit the breakpoint, that register may have been re-used for some other purpose. It can be impossible for the debugger to tell you the value of `i` at that point.

As a general rule, unless the execution of a program depends on the value of a variable, there is no requirement that it be possible to determine that variable's value.

Turning off optimizations can help.

Comment: If this is the case then, say even if I am putting a break point at `if(i>3)` (in your code), still it is not working !

Comment: i won't have a value, because the compiler may have been smart enough to just use a register for the value and not map it to any variable in RAM.

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible that the compiler is optimizing it out. A quick trick to make sure a variable will never be optimized out is to declare it as *volatile*. This tells the compiler that the variable should be treated like it could changed at **any** time (such as a global being modified from an interrupt).

Example:

```
int main()
{
   // Even though we never read the value of test, it will not be optimized away
   volatile int test;

   test = foo();

   return 0;
}
```